# not able to open xamarin layout in .net framework

Tags: xamarin

i am using .net framework 2015 with 8 GB ram. my problem is that i am not able to use xamarin with my framework.i am not able to open xamarin layouts.
once i open xamarin layout  this error pops up.

> Something went wrong The opration Createsession failed due to internal
>   error. could not initialize class mono.android.D3ImageFactory Details
>   ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   mono.android.D3DImageFactory  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native
>   Method)   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)  at
>   mono.android.DesignerSession.initializePlatformSpecific(DesignerSession.java:86)
>     at mono.android.DesignerSession.(DesignerSession.java:75)     at
>   mono.android.Project.createSession(Project.java:382)  at
>   mono.android.Project.processMessage(Project.java:414)     at
>   mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
>     at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

please tell me how to troubleshoot this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The answer in [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/99268/xamarin-android-designer-not-working.html) fixed it for me in VS 2015:

First, update to the latest JDK (1.8 update 144). Then in VS go to Tools > Options > Xamarin and select the version of the installed JDK under "C:\Program Files...".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same D3DImageFactory error message when trying to load up the designer.

I went ahead and uninstalled all versions of the jdk and jre and then installed the latest versions from the java website.
when I next went into the axml layout designer no crashes or anything.

I did all this today though. So it could be tomorrow when I boot up my machine I might get the exception again.